# Stripe Connect (Market Place) multiple splits to connected account

Tags: paypal, braintree, marketplace, stripe-connect

We are managing ticketing platform, it's a market place where buyers and sellers interact via our platform. Seller creates event and sells ticket, customer buys ticket (guest & registered) via credit card.

So, initially we have four actors involve in each transaction, they are stripe (payment processor), platform owner, seller & buyer. But, amount splits amongs three actors stripe (payment processor), platform owner & seller.

Ticket Price: 15$ - Seller
Payment processing fee (Stripe):  0.735 (2.9% of principal + 30¢) - Stripe
Application fee: 0.99¢ (fixed) - Platform Owner

Accumulated amount charge from customer will be sum of this, which is $ 16.725 .

We are using stripe connect and it's working fine, using simple charge API. But, now new actor involve in this transaction process, which we wanted to accommodate & we are facing challenges. There is addition of "agency" in our platform who brings seller (event creator) in our platform. Now we wanted to divide split amongs four actors: Stripe, platform, agent & seller.

We research complete stripe documentation.

How we can handle splits among multiple actors using stripe connect. We are open to any other Market Place product as well (brain tree, paypal) but, we preferred Stripe.

Is there any straight forward way of handling this, or any proper workaround by which we can handle this.

Thanks in advance. I can share code if you wanted to but right now wanted to solve problem first on paper.

Comment: Question is about design, not coding! Please review rules for questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Q: I want to distribute payment made into multiple accounts (market place)

A: It sounds like what you're looking for is Connect. With Connect, Stripe makes it easy for platforms to transfer earnings to their users. You can find more information on Connect at the link below:

https://stripe.com/connect
https://stripe.com/docs/connect

Q: If above is possible how many accounts can this amount be distributed in? Is there any limitation

A: Unfortunately, for compliance reasons, we're not currently able to support the splitting of funds from a single charge among multiple connected accounts. As a platform using Connect, you'll want to ensure that there is still a one-to-one relationship between a charge and one of your connected accounts.

However, you can create multiple charges on a card—each corresponding to the respective connected account.

Q: can I receive payments in multiple accounts

bank-account-and-transfers#automatic-transfers

Q: Can I transfer funds from Stripe account to other accounts online

A: While it is technically possible to move funds from your Stripe account to another Stripe account, we recommend avoiding this method. For compliance reasons, the vast majority of money moving around must be directly linked to an incoming charge (either by having been created on the connected account or via use of the `destination` parameter). When you use one of these methods, the funds are never available to you: they will end up either being refunded, or being paid out to the account holder's bank account.

Q: From following options how many are supported on Stripe -- Visa, Mastercard, Amex, Discover, Apple Pay, Samsung Pay, PayPal, Amazon Pay, Bit Coin

A: The card/payment types that you can accept will depend on where you're located. You can see more information on this here:

which-cards-and-payment-types-can-i-accept-with-stripe